# Oauth : Get user's permissions without any redirection to a server

Tags: import, oauth, contacts

in my website, I want to add a "invite friend of my contacts book" functionnality.

I would like that the user fills the loggin form in my website. Then the website contacts Google Mail, Yahoo Mail, Live Mail and retrieves the contact list.

In the Oauth protocole supported by Google and Yahoo, the user is redirected to a Google or Yahoo page (like Facebook) in order to permit the user to give permissions.

But I saw two websites which didn't any redirections to get the contacts book ([LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/) for a Google mail account and Theauteurs with a live mail.)

**Do you know how I can get a contacts book without redirect the user to Google, Microsoft or Yahoo website.**

Answer (score 1):

Simple.  Neither of them are using OAuth to access contact data.  That means users don't get the benefits (such as not having to share passwords and easy revocation).

Answer (score 0):

The motivation behind OAuth is to **avoid users to input their credentials of site A in site B** (this would be you).

If you follow this path (and I believe you should not), you are not doing OAuth at all.

PS: Why Facebook doesn't use OAuth is something that puzzles me still...

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will be dropping Connect in favor of oAuth. Outlined here-> http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2362920,00.asp